# Python TCP networking inconsistencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm new to networking and I'm trying to write a simple TCP client. The first thing I have to do is to send my message length and wait for further instructions. Here's my code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.send(bytearray(message_serialised_length))

data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()
print("response: {}".format(struct.unpack('>I', data)))
```

Sometimes, i'm able to get a response and the program continues but other times I run into this error:
`struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`.
I'm not sure why this happens and how to fix this. What steps should I take and how can I better understand this problem? I tried removing the `struct` library and use `.decode()` instead, but that was giving me empty values.

Comment: You need to write some code to receive a message by receiving the message length and then calling `recv` until it receives that number of bytes. You haven't actually done this yet, so how could you expect it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You received more than 4 bytes and unpack requires exactly four bytes for `'>I'`.  TCP is a streaming protocol.  If the server sends 4 bytes for a message size and then sends the message, and you `recv(BUFFER_SIZE)`, you will get 1 to BUFFER_SIZE bytes or zero bytes if the server closed the connection.  You have to check that you have at least 4 bytes in the buffer, then strip off and convert those bytes to a length, then keep buffering more `recv` calls until you get the number of bytes specified by the message length.

Here's a clear example.  The following server code waits for a client connection, and then sends a random number from 1-1000 of value 0 bytes, then a random number from 1-1000 of value 1 bytes, repeating until a final value byte of 255.  Each stream of the same value is sent in a different `.sendall()` call.

The client will simply connect to the server and call `.recv(4096)`, printing out how many bytes it received along with the unique set of numbers received.  Receiving the same number to two different `.recv` calls indicates the data was split across the two receives.  Receiving more than one number a recv indicates the sends were combined in a receive.

server.py

```
from socket import *
import random

s=socket()
s.bind(('',5000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c,a = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection from {a}')
    with c:
        for i in range(256):
            length = random.randint(1,1000)
            data = bytes([i] * length)
            c.sendall(data)
    print('Disconnected.')
```

client.py:

```
from socket import *
s=socket()
s.connect(('192.168.1.5',5000))
while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if not data: break
    print(len(data),set(data))
```

Output:

```
473 {0}               # All the zeros were recv'd in the first recv
1704 {1, 2, 3}        # Three sends were combined
4096 {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}   # 12s were split across two packets
4096 {12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
4096 {16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
4096 {32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}
4096 {36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42}
4096 {42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51}  # 51 was split across recvs.
3495 {51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59}      # Didn't get a full 4096.
4096 {64, 65, 66, 60, 61, 62, 63} # Note: sets are unordered, so the numbers aren't sequential
1472 {66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71}     # Rarely gets the full 4096 after this point.
839 {72, 73}
1577 {74, 75, 76}
1610 {80, 77, 78, 79}
1566 {81, 82}
124 {83}
285 {84}
2087 {85, 86, 87}
4096 {88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93}
168 {93}
1270 {94, 95}
1737 {96, 97, 98}
1593 {99, 100, 101}
1674 {102, 103}
1290 {104, 105, 106, 107}
1266 {108, 109}
3499 {110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115}
2694 {116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122}  # split 122s even without a full buffer.
666 {122, 123}
1532 {124, 125, 126, 127}
1065 {128, 129}
1121 {130, 131}
1601 {132, 133, 134, 135}
1507 {136, 137}
1055 {138, 139}
1663 {140, 141}
1286 {144, 145, 142, 143}
1796 {146, 147, 148}
2199 {149, 150, 151}
1636 {152, 153, 154}
809 {155, 156}
1462 {157, 158}
576 {159}
656 {160, 161}
1693 {162, 163, 164, 165}
1460 {168, 169, 166, 167}
27 {169}
1679 {170, 171, 172, 173}
505 {176, 174, 175}
736 {177, 178}
3910 {179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185}
1452 {186, 187, 188}
1772 {192, 189, 190, 191}
2112 {193, 194, 195, 196}
1712 {200, 197, 198, 199}
1769 {201, 202}
1024 {203, 204}
984 {205, 206}
339 {207}
1869 {208, 209}
1819 {210, 211}
624 {212}
1474 {216, 213, 214, 215}
1619 {217, 218, 219}
842 {220, 221, 222}
746 {224, 223}
1453 {225, 226}
4096 {227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233}
1514 {233, 234, 235, 236}
1554 {237, 238}
1677 {240, 241, 239}
1450 {242, 243}
522 {244, 245}
377 {246}
1919 {247, 248, 249, 250, 251}
1437 {252, 253, 254, 255}
```

Note that this was run between two separate computers (a "real" situation).  Often using "localhost" and testing client/server on the same machine doesn't fragment the sends at all, which is unfortunate because people learn and test on a single machine and wonder why there code breaks later.

To actually implement messages in TCP, one technique is what appears in the original post code, send the message size, followed by the message.  Here's an example of that:

server.py

```
from socket import *
import random
import struct

s=socket()
s.bind(('',5000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c,a = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection from {a}')
    with c:
        for i in range(256):
            length = random.randint(1,1000)
            data = bytes([i] * length)
            c.send(struct.pack('<I',length)) # send 4-byte length
            c.sendall(data)                  # send actual message
    print('Disconnected.')
```

client.py

```
from socket import *
import struct

class Client:
    '''Buffer the TCP stream and extract meaningful data on message boundaries.'''

    def __init__(self,addr,port):
        self.sock = socket()
        self.sock.connect((addr,port))
        self.buffer = b''

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self,*args):
        self.sock.close()

    def get_raw(self,size):
        '''Request a specific number of bytes to extract from the stream.'''
        while len(self.buffer) < size:
            data = self.sock.recv(4096)
            if not data: # server closed
                return b''
            self.buffer += data
        msg,self.buffer = self.buffer[:size],self.buffer[size:]
        return msg

    def get(self):
        '''Extract a message from the stream.'''
        raw = self.get_raw(4)  # Get the 4-byte length data
        if not raw:
            return b''
        length = struct.unpack('<I',raw)[0]
        return self.get_raw(length) # Return the actual message

with Client('192.168.1.5',5000) as c:
    while True:
        data = c.get()
        if not data: break
        print(len(data),set(data))
```

Output:

```
290 {0}
619 {1}
450 {2}
238 {3}
803 {4}
779 {5}
358 {6}
245 {7}
782 {8}
90 {9}
108 {10}
370 {11}
346 {12}
783 {13}
21 {14}
646 {15}
53 {16}
912 {17}
678 {18}
794 {19}
617 {20}
76 {21}
279 {22}
634 {23}
479 {24}
189 {25}
117 {26}
865 {27}
940 {28}
477 {29}
596 {30}
700 {31}
354 {32}
734 {33}
272 {34}
511 {35}
669 {36}
816 {37}
43 {38}
948 {39}
256 {40}
829 {41}
48 {42}
193 {43}
721 {44}
132 {45}
334 {46}
494 {47}
952 {48}
768 {49}
103 {50}
657 {51}
354 {52}
298 {53}
262 {54}
713 {55}
386 {56}
325 {57}
676 {58}
391 {59}
707 {60}
162 {61}
462 {62}
575 {63}
237 {64}
502 {65}
488 {66}
28 {67}
588 {68}
2 {69}
660 {70}
937 {71}
452 {72}
412 {73}
24 {74}
320 {75}
464 {76}
457 {77}
71 {78}
213 {79}
208 {80}
969 {81}
204 {82}
542 {83}
179 {84}
779 {85}
393 {86}
630 {87}
492 {88}
75 {89}
592 {90}
630 {91}
946 {92}
447 {93}
497 {94}
644 {95}
626 {96}
629 {97}
840 {98}
614 {99}
29 {100}
876 {101}
644 {102}
318 {103}
285 {104}
936 {105}
416 {106}
281 {107}
888 {108}
529 {109}
249 {110}
89 {111}
250 {112}
868 {113}
454 {114}
303 {115}
506 {116}
337 {117}
747 {118}
582 {119}
248 {120}
321 {121}
746 {122}
536 {123}
491 {124}
739 {125}
234 {126}
532 {127}
115 {128}
691 {129}
939 {130}
464 {131}
603 {132}
12 {133}
920 {134}
467 {135}
697 {136}
441 {137}
673 {138}
466 {139}
595 {140}
697 {141}
801 {142}
971 {143}
986 {144}
615 {145}
591 {146}
556 {147}
734 {148}
904 {149}
256 {150}
865 {151}
993 {152}
942 {153}
3 {154}
152 {155}
404 {156}
840 {157}
253 {158}
558 {159}
917 {160}
326 {161}
29 {162}
713 {163}
841 {164}
191 {165}
432 {166}
100 {167}
936 {168}
185 {169}
586 {170}
736 {171}
474 {172}
400 {173}
619 {174}
933 {175}
588 {176}
512 {177}
79 {178}
437 {179}
504 {180}
115 {181}
321 {182}
982 {183}
288 {184}
6 {185}
531 {186}
538 {187}
929 {188}
790 {189}
769 {190}
567 {191}
647 {192}
258 {193}
807 {194}
966 {195}
936 {196}
715 {197}
259 {198}
301 {199}
718 {200}
743 {201}
281 {202}
448 {203}
776 {204}
498 {205}
575 {206}
569 {207}
534 {208}
42 {209}
15 {210}
436 {211}
260 {212}
156 {213}
180 {214}
580 {215}
99 {216}
647 {217}
767 {218}
983 {219}
274 {220}
23 {221}
81 {222}
918 {223}
584 {224}
55 {225}
302 {226}
750 {227}
410 {228}
685 {229}
710 {230}
197 {231}
498 {232}
682 {233}
906 {234}
687 {235}
599 {236}
761 {237}
471 {238}
269 {239}
791 {240}
241 {241}
822 {242}
364 {243}
591 {244}
74 {245}
245 {246}
143 {247}
113 {248}
305 {249}
512 {250}
148 {251}
755 {252}
437 {253}
167 {254}
559 {255}
```

(Can you tell I'm bored @ home during COVID-19 outbreak?)

Comment: I don't really understand when you say " you will get 1 to BUFFER_SIZE bytes or zero bytes if the server...", could you elaborate?

Comment: @Frank The buffer size passed to `.recv()` is a *maximum*.  You can and will receive any number of bytes up to that maximum, with the caveat that receiving zero bytes indicates the data stream closed.  The server can call `.send()` with varying amounts of data and the only guarantee is that you will get the bytes in the same order sent, but not the same "chunks".  A socket is similar to a file...write 10 bytes, then 6 bytes, then 7 bytes to a file, and `.read(1024)`, and you will get 23 bytes...but with sockets it might take two reads and you get 14 bytes and 9 bytes.

Comment: @Frank So sometimes you call `.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` and get 4 bytes, other times you get more.  The server is probably calling `.send()` with 4 bytes of size data, and then `.send()` some more times with the message data.  If there is enough delay between the two sends you might get 4 bytes most of the time, but other times you get 4 bytes of size plus some amount of the message bytes.