# Python socket Select module showing it received to read requests, when it only received one. Why?

Tags: python, sockets, select, python-sockets

I am creating a program where the client enters in the name of a file containing an image. Then it is converted to a numpy array, pickled and sent to the server. The server uses PIL ImageDraw to draw a red X on top of said image then sends it back to the client. I have noticed that the select function adds the socket twice to the read list for some reason. I know this since the client gets the image back and I added a print function at the end of the sending process and it triggered once, but then an earlier print statement went off again, and returned an error. Here is the server output:

```
b'56925          '
sent
b''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 31, in <module>
    msglengthi = int(msglength)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import pickle
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image
import select
import numpy

IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 4321
HEADERSIZE = 15

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen(5)
socketlist = [s]
readqueue = []


while True:
    readqueue, write, exception  = select.select(socketlist, [], [])
    for socket in readqueue:
        if socket == s:
            clientsocket, clientaddress = s.accept()
            socketlist.append(clientsocket)
            print(f"Connection received from {clientaddress}")
            clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server", "utf-8"))
        else:
            msglen = socket.recv(HEADERSIZE)
            msglength = msglen.decode("utf-8")
            print(msglen)
            msglengthi = int(msglength)
            fullmsg = []
            x=0
            while x<=msglengthi:
                msgu = socket.recv(3000)
                fullmsg.append(msgu)
                x+=3000
            fullmsg = b"".join(fullmsg)
            msg = pickle.loads(fullmsg)
            img = Image.fromarray(msg)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            width, height = img.size
            draw.line((0, 0, width, height), fill="red", width=20)
            draw.line((width, 0, 0, height), fill="red", width=20)
            payload = pickle.dumps(numpy.array(img))
            paylen = len(payload)
            socket.send(bytes(f"{paylen:<{HEADERSIZE}}", "utf-8")+payload)
            print("sent")
```

and finally the client code:

```
import socket
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import numpy


PORT = 4321
IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
HEADERSIZE = 15

cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cs.connect((IP, PORT))
welcomemsg = cs.recv(21)
welcomemsg = welcomemsg.decode("utf-8")
print(welcomemsg)

img = input("Enter image file: ")
imgo = Image.open(img)
imga = numpy.array(imgo)
imgdump = pickle.dumps(imga)
msglen = len(imgdump)
print(msglen)
cs.send(bytes(f"{msglen:<{HEADERSIZE}}", "utf-8")+imgdump)
msglen = cs.recv(HEADERSIZE)
msglen = msglen.decode("utf-8").strip()
msglen = int(msglen)
x=0
fullmsg=[]
while x<=msglen:
    msg = cs.recv(3000)
    fullmsg.append(msg)
    x+=3000
fullmsg = b"".join(fullmsg)
img = pickle.loads(fullmsg)
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your return values! `recv(3000)` is *not* guaranteed to return 3000 bytes.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986382/235698) for an example and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have noticed that the select function adds the socket twice to the read list for some reason.

It doesn't. `select` returns that the socket is readable whenever there are information on the socket which can be retrieved using `recv`. While you handle the case that `recv` returns actual data you don't handle the case when `recv` returns an empty buffer (i.e. `''`) which it does if the peer closes the connection. In other words: the problem is not `select` but your assumption of how `select` and `recv` work.

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** I understand it now. Does it work the same with the write part of the function (every time the client is trying to receive something?)

Comment: @ReiMeytal: *"Does it work the same with the write part of the function"* -  I don't really understand what you mean with this.

Comment: What I mean is: Does the write part of select trigger every time a client is listening for a message?

Comment: @ReiMeytal: the write part of select will trigger whenever there is space in the local socket buffer so that a write will not block. It has no information what the peer is currently doing.